# ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to MySQL server on 'db' (115)

Tags: mysql, linux, docker, magento

I am trying to move existing project to Docker. I followed this tutorial at [M.Academy](https://courses.m.academy/courses/set-up-magento-2-development-environment-docker/lectures/9283467) and followed the setup instructions from [Docker on Existing Project](https://github.com/markshust/docker-magento#existing-projects)

While executing trying to connect with MySQL I am getting this error **ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to MySQL server on 'db' (115)**

I also tried to execute: `telnet db 3306`

Response:
Trying 172.17.0.1...
telnet: Unable to connect to remote host: Connection timed out

I tried everything but couldn't figure out the problem. I am new to Docker. I am using Ubuntu 18.04 LTE. Haven't changed db.env and got no error on any other step before importing the database.

I further checked and found out that the container is not able to establish connection with MySQL.

P.S. I am successfully able to connect with same MySQL service outside Docker container by using (external MySQL port) `mysql -h 127.0.01 -u root -p -P 3306`

**Steps To Reproduce**

1. Install Docker & Docker Compose on Ubuntu 18.04
2. Download the Docker Compose template: `curl -s https://raw.githubusercontent.com/markshust/docker-magento/master/lib/template | bash`
3. Replace with existing source code of your existing Magento instance: `cp -R ~/Sites/existing src`
4. Execute: `docker-compose -f docker-compose.yml up -d`
5. Copy files to container: `bin/copytocontainer --all`
6. Import existing database: `bin/mysql < /var/www/magento243.sql`

**Expected Result**
Database should have been successfully imported

**Actual Result**
ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to MySQL server on 'db' (115)

P.S. Issue has already been raised here: https://github.com/markshust/docker-magento/issues/589

**docker-compose.yml**

```
version: "3"

services:
  app:
    image: markoshust/magento-nginx:1.18-5
    ports:
      - "80:8000"
      - "443:8443"
    depends_on:
      - "db"
    volumes: &appvolumes
      - ~/.composer:/var/www/.composer:cached
      - ~/.ssh/id_rsa:/var/www/.ssh/id_rsa:cached
      - ~/.ssh/known_hosts:/var/www/.ssh/known_hosts:cached
      - appdata:/var/www/html
      - sockdata:/sock
      - ssldata:/etc/nginx/certs
    extra_hosts: &appextrahosts
      ## M1 Mac support to fix Docker delay, see #566
      - "app:172.17.0.1"
      - "phpfpm:172.17.0.1"
      - "db:172.17.0.1"
      - "redis:172.17.0.1"
      - "elasticsearch:172.17.0.1"
      - "rabbitmq:172.17.0.1"
      ## Selenium support, replace "magento.test" with URL of your site
      - "magento.test:172.17.0.1"

  phpfpm:
    image: markoshust/magento-php:7.4-fpm-11
    volumes: *appvolumes
    extra_hosts: *appextrahosts
    env_file: env/phpfpm.env

  db:
    image: mariadb:10.4
    command: --max_allowed_packet=256M
    ports:
      - "3306:3306"
    env_file: env/db.env
    volumes:
      - dbdata:/var/lib/mysql
    extra_hosts: *appextrahosts

  redis:
    image: redis:5.0-alpine
    ports:
      - "6379:6379"
    extra_hosts: *appextrahosts

  elasticsearch:
    image: markoshust/magento-elasticsearch:7.9.3-1
    ports:
      - "9200:9200"
      - "9300:9300"
    environment:
      - "discovery.type=single-node"
      ## Set custom heap size to avoid memory errors
      - "ES_JAVA_OPTS=-Xms1g -Xmx1g"
      ## Avoid test failures due to small disks
      ## More info at https://github.com/markshust/docker-magento/issues/488
      - "cluster.routing.allocation.disk.threshold_enabled=false"
      - "index.blocks.read_only_allow_delete"
    extra_hosts: *appextrahosts

  rabbitmq:
    image: rabbitmq:3.8.22-management-alpine
    ports:
      - "15672:15672"
      - "5672:5672"
    volumes:
      - rabbitmqdata:/var/lib/rabbitmq
    environment:
      - RABBITMQ_VM_MEMORY_HIGH_WATERMARK=1GB
    extra_hosts: *appextrahosts

  mailcatcher:
    image: sj26/mailcatcher
    ports:
      - "1080:1080"
    extra_hosts: *appextrahosts

  ## Selenium support, uncomment to enable
  #selenium:
  #  image: selenium/standalone-chrome-debug:3.8.1
  #  ports:
  #    - "5900:5900"
  #  extra_hosts: *appextrahosts

volumes:
  appdata:
  dbdata:
  rabbitmqdata:
  sockdata:
  ssldata:
```

Comment: Can you edit the question to include the actual source code you're using, especially the `docker-compose.yml` file?  "Clone this repository then make some changes" is a little hard recipe to follow; try to provide a [mcve] that doesn't require looking outside the question to understand how to reproduce it.

Comment: @DavidMaze Thanks for highlighting this. Updated my question with docker-compose.yml

Comment: Those `extra_hosts:` blocks are odd; they override the [DNS service Compose provides you by default](https://docs.docker.com/compose/networking/) with pointers to an arbitrary IP address.  Does deleting all of the `extra_hosts:` blocks help?

Comment: @DavidMaze - This didn't work

Comment: This answer might also help someone https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70382113/multiple-docker-containers-with-same-images/74543743#74543743

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue was finally resolved by

1. Removing ***extra_hosts*** entries from the YML file
2. Adding ***networks*** in YML

Final **docker-compose.yml**

```
version: "3"

services:
  app:
    image: markoshust/magento-nginx:1.18-5
    ports:
      - "81:8000"
      - "444:8443"
    depends_on:
      - "db"
    volumes: &appvolumes
      - ~/.composer:/var/www/.composer:cached
      - ~/.ssh/id_rsa:/var/www/.ssh/id_rsa:cached
      - ~/.ssh/known_hosts:/var/www/.ssh/known_hosts:cached
      - appdata:/var/www/html
      - sockdata:/sock
      - ssldata:/etc/nginx/certs
    networks:
      - customNetwork

  phpfpm:
    image: markoshust/magento-php:7.4-fpm-11
    volumes: *appvolumes
    env_file: env/phpfpm.env
    networks:
      - customNetwork

  db:
    image: mariadb:10.4
    command: --max_allowed_packet=256M
    ports:
      - "3307:3306"
    env_file: env/db.env
    volumes:
      - dbdata:/var/lib/mysql
    networks:
      - customNetwork

  redis:
    image: redis:5.0-alpine
    ports:
      - "6379:6379"
    networks:
      - customNetwork

  elasticsearch:
    image: markoshust/magento-elasticsearch:7.9.3-1
    ports:
      - "9201:9200"
      - "9301:9300"
    environment:
      - "discovery.type=single-node"
      ## Set custom heap size to avoid memory errors
      - "ES_JAVA_OPTS=-Xms1g -Xmx1g"
      ## Avoid test failures due to small disks
      ## More info at https://github.com/markshust/docker-magento/issues/488
      - "cluster.routing.allocation.disk.threshold_enabled=false"
      - "index.blocks.read_only_allow_delete"
    networks:
      - customNetwork

  rabbitmq:
    image: rabbitmq:3.8.22-management-alpine
    ports:
      - "15672:15672"
      - "5672:5672"
    volumes:
      - rabbitmqdata:/var/lib/rabbitmq
    environment:
      - RABBITMQ_VM_MEMORY_HIGH_WATERMARK=1GB
    networks:
      - customNetwork

  mailcatcher:
    image: sj26/mailcatcher
    ports:
      - "1080:1080"
    networks:
      - customNetwork

volumes:
  appdata:
  dbdata:
  rabbitmqdata:
  sockdata:
  ssldata:

networks:
  customNetwork:
```

Comment: Hi @Ahsan, can you please tell , what the thing i need to replace instead of customNetwork.... do i need to give my local ip there ?

Comment: @Sri the 'customNetwork' is a network alias. It could be any string. Just like you name a network

Comment: It shows following error to me "service "db" refers to undefined network customNetwork: invalid compose project"

Comment: Don't forget to add ```networks:
  customNetwork:```

inside docker-compose.yml for the network declaration. See my above attached sample file

Comment: yes ... it is happened due to the host name of the MySQL.... instead of the hostname , I replaced the container name of the database