# Docker ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to MySQL server on 'db' (115)

Tags: docker, magento

i using docker with https://github.com/markshust/docker-magento  . when i in step by step try to import db i got error ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to MySQL server on 'db' (115)
I tried this solution [ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to MySQL server on 'db' (115)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70303468/error-2002-hy000-cant-connect-to-mysql-server-on-db-115).
my yml file

```
    ## Mark Shust's Docker Configuration for Magento
## (https://github.com/markshust/docker-magento)
##
## Version 41.0.2

## To use SSH, see https://github.com/markshust/docker-magento#ssh
## Linux users, see https://github.com/markshust/docker-magento#linux

## If you changed the default Docker network, you may need to replace
## 172.17.0.1 in this file with the result of:
## docker network inspect bridge --format='{{(index .IPAM.Config 0).Gateway}}'

version: "3"

services:
  app:
    image: markoshust/magento-nginx:1.18-5
    ports:
      - "80:8000"
      - "443:8443"
    volumes: &appvolumes
      - ~/.composer:/var/www/.composer:cached
      - ~/.ssh/id_rsa:/var/www/.ssh/id_rsa:cached
      - ~/.ssh/known_hosts:/var/www/.ssh/known_hosts:cached
      - appdata:/var/www/html
      - sockdata:/sock
      - ssldata:/etc/nginx/certs
    extra_hosts: &appextrahosts
      ## M1 Mac support to fix Docker delay, see #566
      - "app:172.17.0.1"
      - "phpfpm:172.17.0.1"
      - "db:172.17.0.1"
      - "redis:172.17.0.1"
      - "elasticsearch:172.17.0.1"
      - "rabbitmq:172.17.0.1"
      ## Selenium support, replace "magento.test" with URL of your site
      - "magento.test:172.17.0.1"

  phpfpm:
    image: markoshust/magento-php:7.2-fpm
    volumes: *appvolumes
    env_file: env/phpfpm.env
      
  db:
    image: mariadb:10.1
    command: mysqld --innodb_force_recovery=6 --lower_case_table_names=1 --skip-ssl --character_set_server=utf8mb4 --explicit_defaults_for_timestamp
    ports:
      - "3306:3306"
    env_file: env/db.env
    volumes:
      - dbdata:/var/lib/mysql



  redis:
    image: redis:6.0-alpine
    ports:
      - "6379:6379"

  elasticsearch:
    image: markoshust/magento-elasticsearch:7.9.3-1
    ports:
      - "9200:9200"
      - "9300:9300"
    environment:
      - "discovery.type=single-node"
      ## Set custom heap size to avoid memory errors
      - "ES_JAVA_OPTS=-Xms1g -Xmx1g"
      ## Avoid test failures due to small disks
      ## More info at https://github.com/markshust/docker-magento/issues/488
      - "cluster.routing.allocation.disk.threshold_enabled=false"
      - "index.blocks.read_only_allow_delete"

  rabbitmq:
    image: rabbitmq:3.8.22-management-alpine
    ports:
      - "15672:15672"
      - "5672:5672"
    volumes:
      - rabbitmqdata:/var/lib/rabbitmq
    env_file: env/rabbitmq.env

  mailcatcher:
    image: sj26/mailcatcher
    ports:
      - "1080:1080"

  ## Selenium support, uncomment to enable
  #selenium:
  #  image: selenium/standalone-chrome-debug:3.8.1
  #  ports:
  #    - "5900:5900"
  #  extra_hosts: *appextrahosts

volumes:
  appdata:
  dbdata:
  rabbitmqdata:
  sockdata:
  ssldata:
```

Comment: All those extra hosts and port mappings look very suspicious. Why don't you just rely on compose automatic name mapping?

Comment: Could you try to run `docker log container-id` to inspect the issue, then quote it here?

Comment: Also, let's check the file app/etc/env.php is exist

Answer (score 0):

Remember that you will need to connect to the running docker container. So you probably want to use TCP instead of Unix socket. Check the output of the docker ps command and look for running MySQL containers. If you find one then use MySQL command like this: MySQL -h 127.0.0.1 -P <mysql_port> (you will find a port in docker ps output). If you can't find any running MySQL container in docker ps output then try docker images to find MySQL image name and try something like this to run it: docker run -d -p 3306:3306 tutum/MySQL where "tutum/MySQL" is image name found in docker images.